# Low cost tablet just to watch videos with at least a 25cm (10") screen - any OS

Tags: audio, tablet, video, speakers, audio-quality

I'm looking for a cost-efficient tablet just to watch videos.  So the most important things are:

1. Great screen, at least 25cm (10") diameter, viewable at a reasonably wide angle (an angle similar to an average modern-day computer monitor)
2. Smooth video playback
3. WiFi (any type is fine, but prefer at least 802.11b)
4. Sufficient battery life to play 2 hours of video non-stop
5. Speakers that sound good for human voices (if they work good for TED talks, they will work good for all my uses, which does include a few TED talks). Stereo speakers would be *real* nice, but are not a hard requirement.
6. Prefer something not too heavy, but I don't have specific weight requirements

Most of the videos are available on YouTube or YouTube clones.  The rest of the videos are stored as files, which I can convert to any open format before temporarily placing them on the tablet to watch.

I don't need to store a whole bunch of videos on the tablet at any one time.  The longest video that will be watched is likely 2 hours long.  For anything longer, I can plug it in to a charger.

I'm completely open to any operating system, even obscure ones.  Compatibility with any OS version is fine: I don't require compatibility with the "latest-and-greatest" OS version, as I'm just going to be using it to watch videos.

I don't have a specific price range in mind; I would simply like to spend as little as possible while meeting all the above requirements.

Leading up to this posting question, I bought an inexpensive tablet, and the screen was so awful I had to send the tablet back.  The brightness of the screen was so low it was hard to see and you had to line up your eyes within a few degrees perpendicular to the plane of the screen to see the content.  On top of that, the resolution was so bad I could easily see each pixel.

Answer (score 1):

A [Kindle Fire HD 10](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07K1RZWMC) seems like a good option for your needs.  It has a 1080p screen, stereo speakers, and WiFi.  I'm not sure how good the battery life is, but the listing advertises 12 hours of mixed usage, so it should hit the 2-hour goal just fine.

You can use the YouTube website to stream videos, but if you need the YouTube app on it, you can sideload it pretty easily (I've done it if you need help :D) .

If you are willing to get a [refurbished model](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01MEG2HXP), they are $40 cheaper.

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation as well as your kind offer to help sideload the YouTube app.  Do you know if SkyTube will work on that device?  I personally find it much better than the YouTube app.  It's main page is here: https://skytube-app.com/

Comment: Yup! That'll work great!  As long as you know how to sideload APK's on android.  If not, just ask me.

Comment: I haven't purchased the Fire 10 tablet yet, and I came across this one too: https://www.amazon.com/Lenovo-Android-Octa-Core-Processor-ZA5T0263US/dp/B083JVJQH4.  Any thoughts on that one compared to the Fire 10?